# Spring data Exists By Name and Different value for other field

Tags: java, spring-data

There is a way in Spring Data to find if exists a Name that not contains a Code?

Something like:

```
existsNameWithDifferentCode(String name, Long code);
```

I'm doing a update and I have to check if this update doesn't contain the same Name as another.

If I cannot do this with the Spring Data signature method, there is a way to do that with ExampleMatcher?

Or any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this method name

```
existsByNameAndCodeNot(String name, Long code);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write a [JPQL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) request.

This approach will allow you to more accurately obtain the necessary data from the database without:

```
thatLongNameForShortRequestWithMultipleConditions()
```